# mysQL Query help regarding find text

Tags: php, sql, mysql, escaping

I need to get all rows in which `eventname` field contains this text (including single quote)

```
's Birthday
```

I tried this but it is giving error:

```
select * from fab_scheduler where eventname like '%\'s Birthday%'
```

How do i construct such query?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at your username, I feel safe to say that `mysql_real_escape_string` (see my answer below) is also available in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php :-)

Comment: @Jon: Yup, you are right, forgot about that completely... thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to include 's in your SQL, you need to [escape](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html) it:

> There are several ways to include
>   quote characters within a string:
>
> - A “'” inside a string quoted with “'” may be written as “''”.
> - A “"” inside a string quoted with “"” may be written as “""”
> - Precede the quote character by an escape character (“\”)
> - A “'” inside a string quoted with “"” needs no special treatment and
>     need not be doubled or escaped. In the
>     same way, “"” inside a string quoted
>     with “'” needs no special treatment.

Additionally, if you are constructing the SQL in a program, you should strongly consider escaping variables that go into SQL queries by using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) or its equivalent in your programming language. Failure to do so will make your application vulnerable to SQL injection attacks by whomever controls the data source for said variables (probably your users; keep in mind that "your users" can mean "the whole internet" depending on circumstances).

Edit: Quoted the dev.mysql.com instructions above.

Answer (score 1):

Either use double quotes, or escape the single quote.

```
select * from fab_scheduler where eventname like "%'s Birthday%"

select * from fab_scheduler where eventname like '%''s Birthday%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from fab_scheduler where eventname like "%'s Birthday%"
```